# ordered set notation in functions

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functions, notation

*Do please forgive me, if this question is a duplicate.*

How does one correctly notate a function $f$, which takes a ordered subset $S$ from the field $\mathbb{K}$ and returns an other (ordered) subset from the same field in question?

Obviously, the notation $f:S \mapsto T : \text{ ...} \qquad (S,T \subseteq \mathbb{K})$ is invalid, as the function would now take one element from the subset $S$ instead of the subset itself.

I believe, that the correct representation of a ordered set/list would be a tuple $ a := (a_1, a_2, .... , a_n) \in \mathbb{K}^n$, but my issue with the function $f$ is, that the tuple size $n$ is not always defined.

---

*This is not a specific task/problem, where I need the notation requested - it is more out of general interest.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{K})\to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{K})$$
Where $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{K})$ denotes the power set of $\mathbb{K}$.

Comment: But the subsets where "ordered"?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma You are right Sir, that the power set does not implicate  an ordered set, I however will specify this when I need it in future proofs/explanations/...